Excel VBA fails to correctly send arguments to Fortran DLL if argument list has changed, unless I change the DLL file name
I have a Fortran DLL (made using one of the latest Intel oneAPI IFORT compilers) and linked in Visual Studio 2019. One of the entry points contains an argument list of a mixture of Integer4 (Long in VBA) scalars and Real8 (Double in VBA) arrays. I call the function from Excel VBA using a Declaration like this (simplified to make it easy to follow):
Declare PtrSafe Function GetCatalyst Lib "myDll.dll" Alias "#3" (arg1 As Long, arg2 as Long, arg3 As Double, arg4 As Long, arg5 as Long, arg6 As Double) As LongPtr

Where arg1, arg2, arg4, arg5 are just scalar Long values, and arg3 and arg6 are Double arrays with length defined by one of the Long arguments e.g. arg3 is Double(1 to arg2). There are more like 20 arguments, but they follow this pattern.
The Excel call looks something like:
Dim arg1 as Long, arg2 as Long, arg3() as Double
Dim arg4 as Long, arg5 as Long, arg6() as Double

ReDim arg3(1 to arg2)
ReDim arg6(1 to arg5)

'< Some code to make sure the DLL is loaded using LoadLibrary happens here>

' Actual call here
Dim result as Long
result = GetCatalyst(arg1, arg2, arg3(1), arg4, arg5, arg6(1))


This all works fine, all the arguments are properly dimensioned in VBA to match the underlying function in Fortran, BUT then we tried adding another trio of arguments in the middle of the block of arguments, following the same pattern (another Long, Long and Double array). After this, the last three arguments in the list received junk values in the Fortran call, despite VBA apparently passing the correctly initialised values in.
Obviously we checked (and double, even triple checked) the new arguments are properly included in the Fortran (and this had built correctly with the expected compiler-generated interface definition) and that the VBA Declaration AND function call had both correctly been adapted to accommodate the new arguments. We even made a test Fortran application to load and call the DLL and this worked fine.
Finally, we tried loading the DLL function from the function NAME instead of the Ordinal number ("GETCATALYST" instead of "#3") and this worked. We also tried compiling with a new (previously unused) ordinal number #17 and this also worked. Finally, we tried renaming the compiled DLL and loading this with the same original ordinal of #3, which also worked.
Does anyone know how VBA loads ordinal aliases for external DLL calls? It seems that it somehow caches the ordinal alias and shape/size of the arguments for that function somewhere, and only clears it when you supply a new file name for the DLL? We cannot work out what is going wrong, but it seems to be an Excel VBA issue, and seems to be specifically around using ordinal aliases for Fortran DLL calls.
Excel version is o365 build 2407.
Update: based on feedback (thanks!) I should clarify that the erroneous behaviour (junk arguments being passed from VBA into Fortran) persists even after a full machine restart, so it does not look like a per-session cache of the DLL entry point, but something more persistent.

There is Fortran DLL, there is Visual Studio 2019, but how is that related to Excel? How exactly is the function called from Excel? I am missing the connection to Excel here.

See edit, but this is a distraction, I think - the issue is that it all works as expected apart from when the DLL entry point arguments change size/shape without the DLL name/alias also changing? So the calling syntax is evidently correct, it is only the Declaration statement that seems to cause problems, as it looks like Excel is caching the arguments for a particular DLL-entry-point combination, and does not refresh these.

IMO there is no caching of the external DLL in Excel VBA. If you close Excel and open it again and call the function, this should load that DLL again into Excel process.

I think you should generally expect VBA loading of native routines to be a thin wrapper around the Windows API LoadLibrary / GetProcAddress functions.  You didn't mention if you restarted Excel in between the changes, and it's possible that if you did a delete / copy sequence, the old dll is still hanging around as a zombie kept alive by the reference from the still-running Excel instance.

Thanks for the feedback, that is an oversight on my OP - I have updated with more detail. It's certainly very weird behaviour, hence me posting on here...

Does use of the "Compile VBA Project" menu item (under the Debug menu in the VBA environment) have any influence on the behavior?  Maybe there's an issue with Excel incorrectly missing that it needs to recompile.

Were in the VBA do you reference (in the core or not) the Fortran DLL ?

@Craig, I don't think the "Compile VBA Project" solved it, from memory, and in any case, the issue persisted after closing and reopening the file (and Excel.exe), so I don't think this can be the case, as Excel must compile a VBA project at least on file load?

@Olórin, I am not totally sure I understand your question. The VBA Declaration is in a regular Module and the actual function call is in a Class Module, if that's what you mean?
